# How to calculate the position of a mobile device using cell tower info?

Tags: math, triangulation, cellular-network

How would I calculate the position of a mobile device if I have the following information for three towers:
Location, Power TX, Power RX, TX gain, RX gain, and Freq?

Location: 35.1740° N, 79.3923° W
Power TX: 200 watts
Power RX: 4.36
TX Gain:1
RX Gain:1
Freq:913 MHz

Answer (score 0):

Use Friis transmission equation (don't forget about Free-space path loss) for each tower. Which gives you the distance between a given tower and the mobile device. Use the three distances to pinpoint the location by triangulation